# Unable to get Bcc from server with cron job

Tags: email, yii, cron

I am working on web app in Yii and I am trying to save when email receive and i am getting all things like to, cc and body but i am not able to get Bcc.
I am using the following code to get Bcc :

```
$Bcc=$this->getBcc($inbox,$email_number);
```

And i am using the

```
$Cc=$this->getCc($inbox,$email_number);
```

and it is showing the cc. But why the above code for Bcc is not working. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `$this`, do you use a imap class? What means "not working", does it return a null response? Which Yii version do you use? What's the reference to cron jobs? Do you try to get BCC addresses from incoming or outgoing mails?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: I am using the imap api

Comment: imap_headerinfo($inbox,$mid); This function returning the cc but not the bcc field please help me